# getting values from multiple selection on combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, telerik, telerik-combobox

I have a radcombobox that has a checkbox before the item name.

**here is my code.**

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="cbx1" runat="server" Skin="Default" CheckBoxes="true" EmptyMessage="Sample">
                                <Items>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="sample1" Value="1" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="sample2" Value="2" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="sample3" Value="3" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="sample4" Value="4" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="sample5" Value="5" />


                                </Items>
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

how can i get the value of a multiple value of the combobox.

i tried using this code but it doesnt give me values.

```
if (cbx1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    strcbx = string.Empty;
                    foreach (var item in cbx1.CheckedItems)
                    {
                        strcbx = "'" + item.value + "'";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Is there an item.SelectedValue property? or item.Value?

Comment: i add item.value but it gives me only one value even if I check two items

Comment: Right, it should give you the value of the current item in the loop and in the next iteration of the loop it should give you the next item's value and append it to strcbx. But perhaps the RadComboBox behaves differently.

Comment: how can i do this?  i tried to change this strcbx += "'" + item.Value + "," + "'";

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint inside the foreach loop and see what item.Value is set to? I just tried out a small sample page with your code and it looks to be working correctly with the += instead of just = while setting strcbx

Comment: when i click on sample 3 and 5 it will give me only "3" value

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 string items = "";
    if (RadComboBox1.CheckedItems.Count>0)
    {
        foreach (RadComboBoxItem item in RadComboBox1.CheckedItems)
            items += item.Text+ ",";
    }
    Response.Write(items);``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (cbx1.CheckedItems.Count>0)
            {
               string strcbx = string.Empty;
                foreach (var item in cbx1.CheckedItems)
                {
                    strcbx += "'" + item.value + "'" +",";
                }
                string listvalue = strcbx.TrimEnd(',');
            }
```

Comment: Hi, some explanations would significantly improve the quality of your answer

Comment: Hi, First check this checkbox item checked, then I declare a variable where store value from check box checked item, then i store value using foreach loop and separate value using "," finally i show value as a string without last comma.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get value with coma separate then use this code

```
string items = "";
items = string.Join(",", RadComboBox1.CheckedItems.Select(d => d.Value).ToArray())
```